# Autofilling Textboxes with Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I check if the user is logged in with, if they are then i pull their details from the database, i then want to auto fill this data into part of my form.

```
while(OCIFetch($stmt)) {
    if(OCIResult($stmt,"PASSWORD")==$Password) {
        $flag=true;

        $First=OCIResult($stmt,"FIRSTNAME");
        $Sur=OCIResult($stmt,"SURNAME");
        $Email=OCIResult($stmt,"EMAIL");
        $Phone=OCIResult($stmt,"PHONE");
        $Address=OCIResult($stmt,"ADDRESS");
        $City=OCIResult($stmt, "CITY");
        $Post=OCIResult($stmt, "POSTCODE");
        //set up session - Declare session variables and assign their corresponding values
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['RegUser'] = OCIResult($stmt,"USERNAME");
        $_SESSION['RegFirst'] = $First;
        $_SESSION['RegSur'] = $Sur;
        $_SESSION['RegEmail'] = $Email;
        $_SESSION['RegPhone'] = $Phone;
        $_SESSION['RegAdd'] = $Address;
        $_SESSION['RegCity'] = $City;
        $_SESSION['RegPost'] = $Post;
    }
```

This is the code im currently attempting to use to auto fill but the fields still appear blank

```
    //Autofill the details if the user is logged in
    window.onload = function() {
        document.forms['Order']['RegFirst'].value = "<?php echo $First?>";
        document.forms['Order']['RegSur'].value = "<?php echo $Sur?>";
        document.forms['Order']['RegEmail'].value = "<?php echo $Email?>";
        document.forms['Order']['RegPhone'].value = "<?php echo $Phone?>";
        document.forms['Order']['RegAdd'].value = "<?php echo $Address?>";
        document.forms['Order']['RegCity'].value = "<?php echo $City?>";
        document.forms['Order']['RegPost'].value = "<?php echo $Post?>";


    }
```

Comment: You are storing the values in a session, but you aren't using the session to display the values? Is that intended?

Comment: Your variable dlecration is wrong in `$_SESSION['RegPost'] = $post;` It should be `$post = $_SESSION['RegPost'];`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this, just echo the values into your html form fields

```
<input id="example" value="<?php echo $Post?>" />
```

Rinse and repeat for all other form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//Autofill the details if the user is logged in
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms['Order']['RegFirst'].value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['RegFirst'];?>";
    document.forms['Order']['RegSur'].value = "<?php echo  $_SESSION['RegSur'];?>";
    document.forms['Order']['RegEmail'].value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['RegPhone'];?>";
    document.forms['Order']['RegPhone'].value = "<?php echo  $_SESSION['RegPhone'];?>";
    document.forms['Order']['RegAdd'].value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['RegAdd'];?>";
    document.forms['Order']['RegCity'].value = "<?php echo$_SESSION['RegCity'];?>";
    document.forms['Order']['RegPost'].value = "<?php echo  $_SESSION['RegPost'];?>";

}
```